# Too many cards in one list possible?

Tags: material-design, cards

I want to setup an app with some cards. I want also to filter this cards. Do you think there is a limit of cards if I have the possibility to reach all cards fast via a e.g. timeline? 
So do you think 5000 cards are to much?

Greetings and Thanks

Simeon

Comment: Hi, can you give us more details on the purpose of the app, and what kind of users it will have? This will help us to give you a more specific answer to your question.

Comment: We would get some regular new differnent notifications which have to be handeled by the user. This action items I would love to show in cards.

Comment: Simeon, to really answer your question we'd need at least a little bit of context. E.g. what kind of user group is that (casual/professional), how big would you want to make the cards (little sketch could help), etc. Cuz otherwise it's just a wild guess. I mean sure if you have filters & search, it shouldn't be a big deal to have many cards but it really depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is expecting to access all their notifications going back to the first day they signed up to your product, you should provide that for them. This has some backend implications in terms of how much data you want to store vs at what point is it sensible to delete old notifications, etc.

As a listing of notifications, how many notifications the user has in the list is not a problem. The problem is how the user can navigate through them.

I think Gabriel's infinite scrolling solution could work but only in conjunction with a date filter / timeline.

Imagine accessing notifications from 2 years back. Only using infinite scrolling would require the user to scroll through 2 years of notifications to see those old ones. Check how Facebook handles their notifications and Timeline. It is a lot of scrolling.

Implementing some sort of timeline or date filter will allow the user to first navigate to the year/month/date and then search for the notification. You could activate infinite scroll at the year and month level, but load all the notifications if the user specifies a date.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an approach of a infinite scroll loading content as the user scrolls down. Loading all 5000 cards is not a good option for too many reasons. But the main reasons i think are:

- Loading these cards can be very slow, imagine fetching 5000 cards from the server? Too expensive.
- Depending on technologies used scrolling down in a view with too many cards can be visually very slow.
- Also the rendering process can feel like it's broken.

So infinite scroll is a great option since you'll load all cards by user demand as it scrolls down. For the filter you would not filter the results on screen, it would not be good to fetch all data and filter on screen, you'll need to filter on the server side of your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. yeah we would not load all cards. Thank you for oyur input.